# Finding a set of 9 integers that minimize an error function

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra

I have an algorithm that takes a 3d triangle PMN(which is constructed from running a function that converts per-vertex UV coordinates to a PMN triangle) and P' which is a randomly chosen 3D point that is outside the plane of PMN and constructs two new 3D points (M', N') where the new points correspond to the same(with a small error margin) UV coordinates

My goal is to construct a PMN triangle such that every value is very close to a whole number eg:

```
(27.007, -26.995, 73.997), (-155.005, 74.001, -4.0041) (31.992, -195.9993, -15.00081)
```

would be valid as the error margin here is acceptable

A bruteforce approach where i choose a random P' between some range and then compare each value of the resulting M' and N' against an epsilon is only feasible when epsilon is quite large(using an epsilon of 0.005 and P' range of -200 to 200 takes about 100ms to compute on average) which is acceptable only if the input is a small amount of triangles

I am looking for an algorithm that would allow me to compute P', M', N' with a small epsilon(anything below 0.01 would be considered acceptable) in a reasonable time as the bruteforce approach is extremely slow as epsilon gets smaller(like i mentioned above it takes ages to run even if the epsilon is 0.05)

My error function is defined as:

```
    private TriangleUV getError(TriangleUV a, TriangleUV b) {
        return new TriangleUV(
                abs(a.u1() - b.u1()),
                abs(a.u2() - b.u2()),
                abs(a.u3() - b.u3()),
                abs(a.v1() - b.v1()),
                abs(a.v2() - b.v2()),
                abs(a.v3() - b.v3())
        );
    }
```

where the first input is the original triangle UV coordinate and the second input is the UV coordinate constructed from pPrime, mPrime, nPrime

PMN to UV function which implements the algorithm described here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/185427/147479

```
    public TriangleUV computeUVFromPMN(int face, Vector3D p, Vector3D m, Vector3D n) {

        float[] u = new float[3];
        float[] v = new float[3];

        int faceA = faceIndicesA[face];
        int faceB = faceIndicesB[face];
        int faceC = faceIndicesC[face];
        Vector3D a = new Vector3D(verticesXCoordinate[faceA], verticesYCoordinate[faceA], verticesZCoordinate[faceA]);
        Vector3D b = new Vector3D(verticesXCoordinate[faceB], verticesYCoordinate[faceB], verticesZCoordinate[faceB]);
        Vector3D c = new Vector3D(verticesXCoordinate[faceC], verticesYCoordinate[faceC], verticesZCoordinate[faceC]);

        final Vector3D PM = m.subtract(p);
        final Vector3D PN = n.subtract(p);
        final Vector3D PA = a.subtract(p);
        final Vector3D PB = b.subtract(p);
        final Vector3D PC = c.subtract(p);

        final Vector3D PMxPN = PM.crossProduct(PN);

        final Vector3D U = PN.crossProduct(PMxPN);
        double Mu = 1.0F / U.dotProduct(PM);
        double uA = U.dotProduct(PA) * Mu; /* 1st U coordinate (for vertex A) */
        double uB = U.dotProduct(PB) * Mu; /* 2nd U coordinate (for vertex B) */
        double uC = U.dotProduct(PC) * Mu; /* 3rd U coordinate (for vertex C) */

        final Vector3D V = PM.crossProduct(PMxPN);
        double Mv = 1.0 / V.dotProduct(PN);
        double vA = V.dotProduct(PA) * Mv; /* 1st V coordinate (for vertex A) */
        double vB = V.dotProduct(PB) * Mv; /* 2nd V coordinate (for vertex B) */
        double vC = V.dotProduct(PC) * Mv; /* 3rd V coordinate (for vertex C) */

        u[0] = (float) uA;
        u[1] = (float) uB;
        u[2] = (float) uC;

        v[0] = (float) vA;
        v[1] = (float) vB;
        v[2] = (float) vC;


        return new TriangleUV(u[0], u[1], u[2], v[0], v[1], v[2]);
    }
```

So essentially i would want to construct P', M', N' values that are very close to whole numbers such that
`getError(originalUV, computeUVFromPMN(P', M', N')).sum() < someSmallValue`

Definitions:
a UV coordinate assigns a point in an image to a vertex(it is used in texture mapping) and then those UV coordinates are interpolated

a PMN triangle also defines a texture map, the texture coordinates are directly calculated from the basis vectors:

```
P defines the origin of the texture(corresponds to (u, v) = (0, 0))
M defines the horizontal end of the texture(corresponds to (u, v) = (1, 0))
N defines the vertical end of the texture(corresponds to (u, v) = (0, 1))
```

Current step by step brute-force algorithm to find PMN values close to a whole number:

```
Input: triangle ABC, UV coordinates for each vertex of the triangle
1) Compute PMN triangle for the triangle ABC from the UV coordinates
2) Pick a random point P' that is outside of the plane of PMN
3) Compute M' and N' by projecting M and N to a new plane through P', perpendicular to d
4) check if each value of P', M', N' is close(checked against an epsilon) to a whole number
if not keep iterating(each iteration a new random P' is picked)
otherwise we have found a valid PMN triangle
```

Computing d, M' and N':

$$\vec d = \frac {P^\prime - P}{||P^\prime - P||}$$
$$M^\prime = P^\prime + (M - P) - \vec d \left(\left(M-P\right)\cdot \vec d \right)\\
N^\prime = P^\prime + (N - P) - \vec d \left(\left(N-P\right)\cdot \vec d \right)$$

Output of the algorithm: a PMN triangle
Output has the satisfy the above condition: `getError(originalUV, computeUVFromPMN(P', M', N')).sum() < someSmallValue`
Where sum is defined as:

```
    public float sum() {
        return u1 + u2 + u3 + v1 + v2 + v3;
    }
```

Comment: I think it might help here if you collapse down your error function to something you can state more concisely, so folks don't have to peel back through two other Q&A threads on a different site to understand the problem you're solving.

Comment: thank you, edited.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding what problem you are trying to solve.  You say you want to construct a triangle with whole-number coordinates, but what other requirements do you have?  The triangle (1,2,3) has whole-number coordinates, but I doubt you're going to be happy with that, so I suspect you have other requirements not articulated.  If you're looking for an algorithm to do something, can you identify the inputs to the algorithm, the desired outputs, and the conditions under which the output is considered acceptable/correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a PMN triangle or UV coordinates.  Are those technical terms with some formal definition?  If so, can you define those terms?  I don't understand what you mean by "the new points correspond to the same UV coordinates".  Same as what?

Comment: Can you describe the objective function in a way that doesn't require me to read and understand a bunch of code?

Comment: @D.W. i have updated the question, is it more clear now? if not can you let me know what else i could improve.
I could also include the algorithm for computing PMN from UV if that would help(im just not sure whether to post it as raw code with an explanation of how it works or link to a SE answer that describes the algorithm in math notation)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not clear for me.  The update addresses some details but I don't understand the big picture.  What are the inputs to the algorithm?  What are the outputs?  What condition must the outputs satisfy, for them to count as correct?  Can you give us some intuition about what the objective function is computing, so we can understand it without reading the code or some other algorithm?

Comment: I have updated it again, is this a little more clear now or can i improve it more?